# Circular View with Button Press Effect

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-custom-view

I am looking for a custom component to design a circular remote control view like the image below with different button and background color.

[image]

Each button should be touchable with proper press effect. I did find a useful [library](https://github.com/dmitry-zaitsev/CircleLayout) with this I am able to create somewhat similar design but still there are lots of improvement required like Press effect/ Inner and outer circle padding radius etc. Please help me to find the better option for this.

Comment: You don't even need a custom View for that. You can simply use a RelativeLayout and 5 ImageViews or TextViews in it. It's a game of images (or even drawables) and StateLists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[image]

I think tihs is your answer.
You can download here.
https://code.google.com/p/radial-menu-widget/

Comment: It's really great, Can we use this widget inside a Layout?

Comment: Absolutely you can use.
This is the other sample library.
https://github.com/strider2023/Radial-Menu-Widget-Android

Answer (score 1):

You could make your own class extending view. You will then be able to override onDraw() and draw whatever you want.

You could also use default android Button with a custom xml selector defined with a different image ressource for pressed/not pressed states.